# AWS Lambda default VPC - unable to connect with mongodb running on EC2

Tags: mongodb, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-lambda, amazon-vpc

Can anyone help me to figure out database connection issue from Lambda to MognoDB (running on EC2, ubuntu machine)

I have following scenario -

1. Installed and running MongoDB on EC2 (it is in default VPC)
2. Enable port 27017 for private IP of API EC2
3. Enable port 27017 for SECURITY_GROUP, like this -
   [image]
4. Deployed Lambda function within default VPC and the same security group as assigned to MongoDB EC2 server.
   [image]

With above situation my Lamda function is not able to connect with MongoDB EC2 server, however if I open the PORT 27017 globally, then it is working fine.

Can anyone help please?

Comment: By #3, do you mean that the security group assigned to the MongoDB instance allows inbound port 27017 from the security group itself?

Comment: @jarmod - Yes correct

Comment: When your Lambda function connects to the MongoDB instance, is it doing this via hostname or public IP or private IP?

Comment: It is using public IP of mongoDB instance

Comment: That's the problem. You should be resolving the DNS name (which will resolve to the private IP if using the standard VPC-supplied DNS server) or just use the private IP directly. Using the public IP means that your client is no longer seen as being in the security group and hence your traffic is dropped (unless you allow inbound from its public IP or 0.0.0.0/0).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given that the Lambda function and MongoDB instance have the same security group, you should:

- ensure that the security group allows traffic inbound from itself
- your DB client connects to the private IP of the DB server (or resolves its DNS name using the VPC DNS resolver, which will yield the private IP) rather than its public IP